# What happens to the file descriptor table in parent process after calling dup2 and execvp in the child process?

Tags: c, process, exec, dup2

I am coding a simple shell program but unsure of what happens to the file descriptor table after dup2() and execvp. So I have a parent process waiting for child process to end(waitpid) but when it loops back to wait for the next user input, how come does the file descriptor table I modified using dup2 in child process not persist in the parent process? Is it because execvp resets the file descriptor table back to the original?

EDIT: I figured it out. The fork function actually makes a separate copy of the program image, including file descriptor table so the parent process's fd table is unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing. The child process gets a copy of the parent's file descriptors when it's created by `fork()`, but changes it makes after that aren't shared back to the parent.

(Note that, while the file descriptor **table** is not shared with the parent, the state of the file descriptors themselves is! For instance, if you `seek()` on a file descriptor that a child process inherited from its parent, that affects the copy in the parent as well.)